# Use local file as source for html video tag

Tags: html, html5-video

I am trying to use a local file as the source for my html tag but whenever I try this code nothing works

```
<video src="file:///C:/Users/Videos/server_videos/first.mp4" controls></video>
```

I have tried converting the file into a Blob link however that doesn't work either.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score -1):

`</video>` Doesn't have an attribute named `src`. You will need to add in the `</video>` container a `<source>` tag, which has the `src` attribute.

Try this:

```html
<video controls>
  <source src="file:///C:/Users/sbucarion1/Videos/server_videos/first.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```